# MSP 430G2553 Keypad Error

Tags: msp430, texas-instruments, keypad

I am trying to use 4x3 Keypad with MSP430G2553.

I used code from [electronicwings site](https://www.electronicwings.com/ti-launchpad/4x4-keypad-interfacing-with-msp-exp430g2-ti-launchpad)

```
#include <Keypad.h>
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
//define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypads
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{'0','1','2','3'},
{'4','5','6','7'},
{'8','9','A','B'},
{'C','D','E','F'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {11, 12, 13, 14}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {7, 8, 9, 10}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

//initialize an instance of class NewKeypad
Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); 

void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();

    if (customKey){
      Serial.println(customKey);
 }
}
```

But it continuously gives me this error:

> line 39: fatal error #1965: cannot open source file "WProgram.h"

Here is the complete source code

[keypad library](https://www.electronicwings.com/api/download/platform-attachment/425)

How can I fix this problem or is there other way to use keypad with **msp430g2553**

Comment: You need to locate WProgram.h and install it by the sounds of it.

Comment: I use the MSP430 series of MCUs. I have modified many Arduino and other popular MCU I/O drivers to be used with the less popular MSP430. It isn't that hard, but it isn't a beginner project either. It typically takes me a few hours. Less than 1% of the code typically needs to be changed. Find the lowest level code, that is typically what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

`Keypad.h` has the following code snippet:

```
#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif
```

Upon release of Arduino 1.0, the dependency name changed from WProgram.h to Arduino.h, as per [this forum discussion over at the Arduino forums.](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/what-is-wprogram-h-library/125951)

However, you are not using an Arduino. You will need to either find or write a library that works with your microcontroller, or get an Arduino.